# How do I include a template part in a Ruby file

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working with a ruby website app and I'm not familiar with Ruby , I would like to know how you include say a nav template file in a html file, I'm familiar with how you would do this in PHP with require

So this would include the nav section on each page , what is the code to do this in Ruby

Many thanks

Comment: Check out this [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html).
It covers layout features of Action Controller and Action View.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using **erb** to generate your html, you have to add to the corresponding .erb file (in /app/views/*/):

```
<%= render 'nav' %>
```

And then the file *_nav.html.erb* will be included at that point (from the same dir where the includer file is).